# cleaning up a list of values with no missing data

Tags: list-manipulation

Im attempting to clean up a list which has missing elements by inserting the mean feature variable into the missing data

```
list = {{"age", "height", "weight"}, {32, 176, 75}, {27, "", 82}, {24,180, ""}, {"", 183, 89}};
list // TableForm
copylist = list
copylist[[All ;; 5, 1 ;; 3]] // TableForm;
goodsamples = Table[Cases[copylist[[All, i]], _?NumericQ], {i, 3}] // N;
goodSamplesMean = Table[Mean[goodsamples[[i]]], {i, 3}] // N
cleanlist = copylist[[All ;; 5, 1 ;; 3]] /. "" Table[goodSamplesMean[[i]], {i, 3}];
```

Upon running the code i recieve the error message

ReplaceAll::reps: {27.6667 ,179.667 ,82. } is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

What im aiming for is to replace the mean feature variables from

```
goodSamplesMean
```

Such that

```
cleanlist
```

appears as follows

```
cleanlist={{"age", "height", "weight"}, {32, 176, 75}, {27, 179.667, 82}, {24,180, 82.}, {27.6667, 183, 89}};
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) with the default setting for the option [`MissingBehavior`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MissingBehavior.html) gives the desired result:

```
ClearAll[replaceMissing]
replaceMissing[f_: Mean] := Prepend[Transpose[# /. _Missing -> Query[f]@# & /@ 
      Transpose[Rest[# /. "" -> Missing[]]]], #[[1]]] &;

Row[Grid[#, Dividers -> All] & /@ 
   {list, replaceMissing[]@list, replaceMissing[Total]@list}, 
   Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ClearAll[replaceMissing2]
replaceMissing2[f_: Mean] := Prepend[Transpose[# /. _Missing -> f[DeleteMissing@#] & /@ 
      Transpose[Rest[# /. "" -> Missing[]]]], #[[1]]] &;

ClearAll[replaceMissing3]
replaceMissing3[f_: Mean] := Prepend[Transpose[# /. "" -> f@DeleteCases[#, ""] & /@ 
      Transpose[Rest@#]], #[[1]]] &;

replaceMissing[]@list == replaceMissing2[]@list ==  replaceMissing3[]@list
```

> True

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of options.  With

```
list = {{"age", "height", "weight"}, {32, 176, 75}, {27, "", 82}, {24, 180, ""}, {"", 183, 89}};
goodsamples = Select[FreeQ[#, ""] &] /@ Transpose@Rest@list;
goodSamplesMean = Mean /@ goodsamples // N;
```

we can do

```
copylist = With[{pos = Position[list, ""]},
             ReplacePart[list, Thread[pos -> goodSamplesMean[[pos[[All, 2]]]]]]
            ]
(* {{"age", "height", "weight"}, {32, 176, 75}, {27, 179.667, 82}, {24, 180, 82.}, {27.6667, 183, 89}} *)
```

or

```
copylist = list;
Function[copylist[[Sequence @@ #]] = goodSamplesMean[[#[[2]]]]] /@ Position[list, ""];
copylist
(* {{"age", "height", "weight"}, {32, 176, 75}, {27, 179.667, 82}, {24, 180, 82.}, {27.6667, 183, 89}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Transpose` is useful here.

```
(* From the OP: *)
list = {{"age", "height", "weight"}, {32, 176, 75}, {27, "", 82}, {24,180, ""}, {"", 183, 89}};
goodsamples = Table[Cases[list[[All, i]], _?NumericQ], {i, 3}] // N;
goodSamplesMean = Table[Mean[goodsamples[[i]]], {i, 3}] // N


Transpose[
 Table[Transpose[list][[i]] /. "" -> goodSamplesMean[[i]], {i, 3}]]

 (* {{age,height,weight},{32,176,75},{27,179.667,82},{24,180,82.},{27.6667,183,89}} *)
```